# android layouts clashing with layouts

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, layout, android-xml

I am trying to supporting many different android devices and have run into a problem with my layouts, the problem is These layouts are showing only the 5.4 WVGA in the preview pane and the default layout showing wear square/round

layout-large   shows    5.4 WVGA

layout-large-hdpi shows 5.4 WVGA

layout-sw480dp  shows   5.4 WVGA

default layout  shows   wear square/round

these are the only devices it will show in the preview for the folders mentioned! other folders seem fine! i have read the development docs and not sure where i am going wrong to support all screen sizes as thought i had it but was wrong,please see picture i have added to see my layouts.

[image]

Comment: Either use smallest width qualifiers (sw one's) or the size qualifier (large/ small etc). I suggest dropping large, large-hdpi altogether.  Use one default layout folder and sw600dp, sw720dp for larger tablet sized devices.

Comment: would the one default layout folder be sufficient enough to handle all other device screens?

Comment: Depends on your requirements. If you are only targeting phone devices then one single folder will suffice. If you want to provide views optimized for both phones and tablets then use this structure:
layout for phone devices,
layout-sw600dp for 7-10 inch devices,
layout-sw720dp for 10inch tablets and beyond.

Comment: i did originally start with one layout for phones and the sw600dp and sw720dp for tablets however i noticed on some devices like small phones and nexus tablets the layouts didnt quite look right and this is what lead me to making different layout folders with size qualifiers

Comment: I have took you advice and dropped layout large and layout large-hdpi, but still have the issue of the default layout showing only android wear square and round devices!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you ask about preview in Android Studio.

You could change virtual device to render in preview top bar:

[image]

**UPDATE 1**

Check if other device definition exists in Tools > Android > AVD manager 
[image]

Comment: this is why i am asking, when i try this it only displays the 5.4 wvga device as mentioned above, the other layouts belong to different layout folders, i have managed to do one problem however the default layout for some reason is only showing android wear square and round device!

Comment: am i right in thinking the default layout is the same as layout-sw360dp? i think its clashing witht that layout and could be why the default layout is showing me android wear! i will look in the avd manger now though